# Data Generation Results in Violated Unique Constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a table (Major) without any foreign keys and just two fields: ID and Name. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate Database projects to create my tables, etc. I have a Data Generation Plan which is behaving strangely. The Major.Name field is populated via Regular Expression which is an or of 6 values. I have the table configured to generate 5 rows but for some reason VS is showing that the unique constraint on this column is being violated when I run the Data Generation Plan. You can get the demo project here:

http://ayw8ng.blu.livefilestore.com/y1p3NWHwg_0U4sy1q8Jm6AjNzCWlxG8d17infIGmiZG_jlKMxqnpoTpFRM4mbszHSqdS5laTBc3fGvQ5iDSh_4rsvNwl9rvanAl/EnrollmentDemo.zip?download&psid=1

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how things work on SO. Posting a link to something that will eventually go away serves no purpose.  Edit your question to include a minimal example of code that demonstrates your problem and provide all supporting information (i.e. table definition, error messages) and then ask a specific question in that context.

Comment: So you expect me to post every file that may be required to reproduce this inline? That would include project files, properties, SQL files, etc. This is not a feasible recommendation. It seems far more intuitive to just follow the link and have everything there ready to reproduce. If SO is worried about links becoming outdated they should provide a mechanism to attach things to posts.

Comment: well, the link is gone. this thread is worthless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the Seed property of the Regular Expression Column to 0.